# Reduce the font size of the text within a sidebarPanel

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following snippet of code:

```
sidebarPanel(
    selectizeInput(
        "s1",
        "Select s1",
        choices = c('A', 'B'),
        multiple = FALSE
    ),
    radioButtons(
        "r1",
        "Select r1",
        choices = c("A", "B", "C")
    ),
    radioButtons(
        "r2",
        "Select r2",
        choices = c("P", "R")
    ),
    selectizeInput(
        "s3",
        "Select s3",
        choices = c('C', 'D'),
        multiple = FALSE
    ),
    selectizeInput(
        "s4",
        "Select s4",
        choices = c('A', 'B'),
        multiple = TRUE
    ),
    actionButton(
        "b1",
        "Enter"
    )
)
```

Is there a way to reduce the font size, say by 20%, of all the text contained in this sidebarPanel? Alternatively, can I change the font size in each of the selectizeInput or radioButtons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can maybe wrap it in a `div` and style it with `style = "font-size:75%;"`. For `selectizeInput` you will need to do the same as its a different object you can either do it by id or overall with `.selectize-input { font-size: 75%;}`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { font-size: 75%;} .selectize-dropdown { font-size: 75%; }"),
  div(style = "font-size:75%;",
      sidebarPanel(
        selectizeInput(
          "s1",
          "Select s1",
          choices = c('A', 'B'),
          multiple = FALSE
        ),
        radioButtons(
          "r1",
          "Select r1",
          choices = c("A", "B", "C")
        ),
        radioButtons(
          "r2",
          "Select r2",
          choices = c("P", "R")
        ),
        selectizeInput(
          "s3",
          "Select s3",
          choices = c('C', 'D'),
          multiple = FALSE
        ),
        selectizeInput(
          "s4",
          "Select s4",
          choices = c('A', 'B'),
          multiple = TRUE
        ),
        actionButton(
          "b1",
          "Enter"
        )
      )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the line `tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { font-size: 75%;} .selectize-dropdown { font-size: 75%; }"),` out of div?

Comment: The dropdowns have their own classes, so you need to adjust them too, otherwise the selects dropdowns will be larger...

Comment: Another curiosity: can the height of the dropdown menu cells also be reduced?

Comment: Yes, you can add that into the same js code, it has `height:` attribute

Comment: I used `tags$style(type='text/css', ".selectize-input { font-size: 75%; height: 75% } .selectize-dropdown { font-size: 75%; }"),` but the cell height is quite bigger than the font size of the text inside